# Перетаскивание изображения из формы в браузер

Tags: c#, bitmap, drag-n-drop

Имеется задача реализовать возможность перетаскивать изображение из контрола(PictureBox) в браузер (любая форма на странице, например поле ввода в ЛС во вконтакте, и подобными сервисами, поддерживающими прикрепление документов).
На просторах youtube посмотрел множество гайдов о том как делать DragDrop изображений, но все они сводятся к тому, что одно изображение таскают по нескольким PictureBox внутри одной формы. 
Так же подозреваю, что простое перетягивание объекта Bitmap браузером может не поддерживаться, и надо его превратить в массив байт файла и как то указывать тип данных, но никак не придумаю как это реализовать.

**UPD:** в комментариях было подсказано использовать DataObject. Я поигрался с ним перетягивая картинку из браузера в форму, и заметил, что DataObject.GetFormats() помимо url возвращает множество специфичных форматов. Может кто-нибудь подскажет где посмотреть поддерживаемые браузерами форматы?

Answer (score 1):

Подписываете пикчабокс на событие:

```
private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, new[] { path });
        pictureBox.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

`path` - **полный** путь к изображению.

---

В `DataFormats` есть поле `Bitmap`. Соответственно, я пробовал сделать так:

```
new DataObject(DataFormats.Bitmap, pictureBox.Image)
```

Однако, это не работает.

Поискал, какие типы поддерживают браузеры. В частности, на сайте Mozilla 
[Recommended Drag Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#image) написано следующее:

> Direct image dragging is not commonly done. In fact, Mozilla does not support direct image dragging on Mac or Linux platforms. Instead, images are usually dragged only by their URLs.

Вроде как на Windows должно работать? Пока неясно, как это сделать.

Comment: Это конечно вариант! Проблема в том, что изображения лежат в БД в BLOB полях, и хотелось бы их вынимать как-то минуя запись на жесткий диск. В любом случае это уже что-то! Спасибо

Comment: @Pelme666ko - я кое-что нашёл, но в целом вопрос не решён.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если не найдете ничего другого, вешаете хук на обработку событий мыши, затем при клике на pictureBox в окне вашего приложения создаете bitmap, который рисуете поверх всех окон на рабочем столе - (bitmap будет уменьшенной копией изображения в picturebox), этот bitmap будет следовать за курсором до того момента, пока вы не отпустите лкм. При клике копируете изображение из picturebox'a в буффер обмена а в момент отпускания лкм вызываете для конкретного окна под курсором событие paste (ну типа послать нажатие клавиш ctrl+v). Еще вариант используя неуправляемый код создавать событие drag&drop (используя winApi).