# C# drag and drop наоборот

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли в windows forms вытащить файл из формы, захватив его мышкой, как, например, в браузере, открывая меню загрузок, можно вынуть любой файл и переместить на рабочий стол?

Comment: Можно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/832354/184217 Детали зависят от того, что имеется у вас.